# Combining two Insert statement with different "on conflict" clause into one

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two identical insert statement with different `on conflict cause`

Here are the statements

```
INSERT INTO users_list
  (
    account_id,
    name,
    email,
    workspace_id,
    user_state,
    outside_organisation,
    company_user_id,
    service_name
  )
  SELECT
    service_data.account_id,
    new_user_name,
    sent_to,
    workspace_id_value,
    service_data.user_state,
    outside_organisation_value,
    company_user_id_value,
    service_data.service_name
  FROM unnest(email_mapping) AS service_data
  ON CONFLICT (service_name, email) DO UPDATE SET
    account_id = EXCLUDED.account_id,
    user_state = EXCLUDED.user_state;

  INSERT INTO users_list
  (
    account_id,
    name,
    email,
    workspace_id,
    user_state,
    outside_organisation,
    company_user_id,
    service_name
  )
  SELECT
    service_data.account_id,
    new_user_name,
    sent_to,
    workspace_id_value,
    service_data.user_state,
    outside_organisation_value,
    company_user_id_value,
    service_data.service_name
  FROM unnest(name_mapping) AS service_data
  ON CONFLICT (account_id, service_name) DO UPDATE SET
    user_state = EXCLUDED.user_state;
END;
```

Is there a way I can make it look prettier with less code?

**Update**
Here both `email_mapping` and `name_mapping` are table

| column_name | data_type |
| --- | --- |
| account_id | text |
| service_name | text |
| user_state | USER-DEFINED |
| mapping | USER-DEFINED |

the email_mapping would have mapping as `email` and `name_mapping` would have type as `name`

this is postgres function, we pass the data in function parameters.

And this is how `users_list` look

| column_name | data_type | is_nullable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint | NO |
| created_at | timestamp with time zone | NO |
| account_id | text | NO |
| email | text | YES |
| workspace_id | bigint | NO |
| user_state | USER-DEFINED | NO |
| name | text | YES |
| outside_organisation | boolean | YES |
| company_user_id | bigint | YES |
| service_name | text | NO |
| service_role | text | YES |

Comment: Could you explain what those statements do, provide a test schema, test data, and sample expected results? What are `email_mapping` and `name_mapping`? Where do they come from?

Comment: By using Dynamic sql execution

Comment: @Schwern updated

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear. Could you use something like [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S9ZOHCkV) to provide us with a full working example?